# Prove that function f is injective, if function (g o f) is injective as well

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm sort of stuck with this type of proof. Not quite sure how to go about it. I was wondering if someone could help me out to get started with it.

I guess that the two hypotheses I have are these:

g o f(a) = g o f(b)

f(a) = f(b)

and I guess this too:

g o f(a) = g o f(b) -> f(a) = f(b)

I'm studying for a test, and this sort of exercises are the ones I find the toughtest

Comment: No I think he means $g \circ f$ injective $\implies f$ injective

Comment: @T.Bongers If $\mathrm{g}$ is constant (and the domain of $\mathrm{f}$ is not a singleton) then the OP's hypothesis is not met.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a$ and $b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$ then $g(f(a))=g(f(b))$ and since $g\circ f$ is injective then $a=b$ so we have proved:

$$f(a)=f(b)\Rightarrow a=b$$
and we can conclude.

Comment: Yes this works, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.