# If $ g \circ f (x) $ is injective, does that mean that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are also injective?

Tags: functions, examples-counterexamples, function-and-relation-composition

I saw the following proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787016/prove-that-function-f-is-injective-if-function-g-o-f-is-injective-as-well).

---

**Proof:**

Let $f(a) = f(b)$.

Then $g(f(a)) = g(f(b)) \implies g\circ f(a) = g \circ f(b)$

But we know that $g \circ f$ is injective. 
Hence, $a = b$

We have shown that if $f(a) = f(b)$ then $ a = b \implies $ $f(x)$ is injective.

---

In this when we show that $g(f(a)) = g(f(b))$, doesn't it mean that $g(x$) is also injective. If not, why?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at $f(x)= e^x$ and $g(x)= |x|$ (both from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$). Since $e^x>0$ for all $x$ we have $$g(f(x))=|e^x| =e^x$$

so $g\circ f$ is injective, but $g$ is not.

Comment: Can we reason it out just from the proof — without any example?

Comment: But if something is not true then it sufies to find an example that it does not work. Sometimes it can be true, but it is not necesary in general.

Comment: Injectivity as others pointed out is - distinct elements map to distinct images. (1) If you visualize the mappings using Venn diagrams, one possibility is $g$ is injective and hence $g(f(x))$ is injective. (2) Another possibility is the range of $f$ is a subset of the domain of $g$, and all elements in the range have distinct images under $g$. It follows $g(f(x))$ will be injective.

Answer (score 0):

> In this when we show that $g(f(a)) = g(f(b))$, doesn't it mean that
>   $g(x)$ is also injective.

To answer this, let's look at what it means for a function $g: A \rightarrow B$ to be injective. Injectivity says that for all elements $a$ and $b$ in set $A$, if $g(x)=g(y)$ then $x = y$. Or, equivalently that if $x \neq y$ then $g(x) \neq g(y)$. The key is the $\neq$ sign—different values in the domain get mapped to different values in the image.

Here, we're just showing that if $f(a) = f(b)$ then $g(f(a)) = g(f(b))$, which is always true no matter whether or not $g$ is injective. If two elements are equal, like $x = 2$, then no matter whether $g$ is injective, surjective, etc., it's always the case that $g(x) = g(2)$. That's just what it means to when we apply an operation to both sides, like how if $x+5 = 7$ then $x + 5 - 5 = 7 - 5$, which is equivalent to $f(x) = x-5$ and hence $x+5 = 7 \Rightarrow f(x+5) = f(7)$.